# Angular Button to save selected choices

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a button that saves the choices selected by checkboxes, then have each 'selected' value of the objects cleared.

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('FormController', ['$scope', function($scope){

   $scope.goals = [{
            name: 'flex',
            descrip: "Increase Flexibility",
            selec: false,
            submit: ''
    },
    {
            name: 'build',
            descrip: "Build Muscle",
            selec: false,
            submit: ''
    },
    {
            name: 'cardio',
            descrip: "Improve Cardio",
            selec: false,
            submit: ''
   },
   {
            name: 'lose',         
            descrip: "Lose Weight",
            selec: false,
            submit: ''
   }
   ];

 $scope.submitGoals = function(){
  forEach($scope.goals, function(goal, key){
      $scope.goal.submit = $scope.goals.selec;
      $scope.goal.selec = '';



  });
};


}]);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller='FormController'>
    <div class='container col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 panel' >
    <form>
        <span ng-repeat='goal in goals'>
            <input type='checkbox' value='{{goal.name}}' name=selectedGoal[] ng-model='goal.selec'>{{goal.descrip}}
        </span>
        <input type='button' ng-model='submitGoals()' value='Submit'>
    </form>    
</div>

<pre>
    You want to:
        <p ng-repeat='goal in goals' ng-show='goal.selec'>{{goal.descrip}}<br></p>

    <div class='panel-submit'>
        You selected: <p ng-repeat='goal in goals' ng-show'goal.submit'>{{goal.submit}}</p>

    </div>

</pre>

</body>
```

This submitGoals function doesn't work for saving the values, as the {{goal.submit}} expression in html remains blank.

Comment: Suggest you research some tutorials for something like this if you have no background in it. This is neither a tutorial service or a code writing service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should not use the same object to represent submitted goals.

Reason: You may enter something in key "submit" each time the checkbox for that object is checked, but then if the next time its unchecked, you will have to clear the "submit" value.

Following errors were there in your code
1) No ng-app defined in html
2) missing = sign in ng-show at places

You can do something like this in html:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller='FormController'>
    <div class='container col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 panel' >
    <form ng-submit="submitGoal()">
        <span ng-repeat='goal in goals'>
            <input type='checkbox' ng-model="goal.selec">{{goal.descrip}}
        </span>
        <input type='submit' >
    </form>    
</div>

<pre>
    You want to:
        <p ng-repeat='goal in goals' ng-show='goal.selec'>{{goal.descrip}}<br></p>

    <div class='panel-submit'>
        You selected: <p ng-repeat='goal in selectedGoals'>{{goal.descrip}}</p>

    </div>

</pre>

</body>
```

In your controller:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('FormController', ['$scope',      function($scope){

   $scope.goals = [{
            name: 'flex',
            descrip: "Increase Flexibility",
            selec: false,
            submit: ''
    },
    {
            name: 'build',
            descrip: "Build Muscle",
            selec: false,
            submit: ''
    },
    {
            name: 'cardio',
            descrip: "Improve Cardio",
            selec: false,
            submit: ''
   },
   {
            name: 'lose',         
            descrip: "Lose Weight",
            selec: false,
            submit: ''
   }
   ];

   $scope.selectedGoals = [];

$scope.submitGoal = function(){
  angular.forEach($scope.goals, function(goal){

    if(goal.selec){
      $scope.selectedGoals.push(goal);
    }



  });
};


}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You had many errors of formatting. Here is working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5256/

I modified one function to reflect values.

```
   $scope.submitGoals = function(goals){
     $scope.userGoals= [];
     for(var x in $scope.goals)    {
       if($scope.goals[x].selec){
         $scope.userGoals.push($scope.goals[x].descrip);\\Creates array to display submitted values
         $scope.goals[x].selec = false; // Clears selected values
       }
     }
    console.log($scope.userGoals);     
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I have created a plunker based on your code. There seems to be many mistakes. please check the app.js and index.html both for the changes.

https://plnkr.co/edit/a6gNg5wE5C4S5SdCsht7?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller='FormController'>
<div class='container col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 panel' >
<form>
    <span ng-repeat='goal in goals'>
        <input type='checkbox' value='{{goal.name}}' name=selectedGoal[] ng-model='goal.selec'>{{goal.descrip}}
    </span>
    <input type='button' ng-click='submitGoals()' value='Submit'>
</form>    
</div>

<pre>
You want to:
<p ng-repeat='goal in goals' ng-show='goal.selec'>{{goal.descrip}}<br></p>


 You selected: 
 <p ng-repeat='goal in goals' ng-show='goal.submit'>{{goal.descrip}}</p>



 </pre>

 </body>
```

in script

```
$scope.submitGoals = function(){
angular.forEach($scope.goals, function(index,value){

console.log(index);
console.log(index.submit);
index.submit = index.selec;
});
};
```